# I want to install jdk-8u131-linux-i586.tar.gz on a 32 bit system

Tags: java, 32-bit, system, environment

I am using ubuntu 17.04, I am new to ubuntu and I want to install jdk-8u131-linux-i586.tar.gz on my 32 bit system but i dont realy know what to do. Please help me become a good programmer.

Comment: Don't use that tgz file. Google for installing "Java 8 JDK on Ubuntu" and you'll find easier instructions.

Comment: Oracle provide installation instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFCDAIB).